# React.js when using non state variable Getting error as A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use non state variable '***newItem***' to hold the input value

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class List extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { items: [1, 2] };
    this.newItem = undefined;
  }
  changeNewItem = e => {
    this.newItem = e.target.value;
    console.log(this.newItem);
  };
  addItem = e => {
    if (e.keyCode !== 13) return;
    var tmp_list = this.state.items;
    tmp_list.push(this.newItem);
    this.setState({ items: tmp_list }, () => {
      this.newItem = '';
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.items.map(item => (
            <li key={item}>{item}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="add item"
          value={this.newItem}
          onChange={this.changeNewItem}
          onKeyUp={this.addItem}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default List;
```

When I press enter key in textbox the item gets added to the array but getting error as below

index.js:1452 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: 
    in input (at List.js:29)
    in div (at List.js:23)
    in List (at App.js:9)
    in App (at src/index.js:8)

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case is that the initial value of the input element is undefined and then you control it using the variable `this.newItem`. Hence you get the warning which is trying to change an uncontrolled input to controlled.

Initialise the value to `empty string` instead of `undefined`. Also if you want the input component to change value, use state instead of a class variable

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class List extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { items: [1, 2], newItem: '' };
  }
  changeNewItem = e => {
    this.setState({newItem: e.target.value})
  };
  addItem = e => {
    if (e.keyCode !== 13) return;
    var tmp_list = this.state.items;
    tmp_list.push(this.state.newItem);
    this.setState({ items: tmp_list }, () => {
      this.state.newItem = '';
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.items.map(item => (
            <li key={item}>{item}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="add item"
          value={this.state.newItem}
          onChange={this.changeNewItem}
          onKeyUp={this.addItem}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default List;
```

Comment: i'm trying to understand,can we solve this issue without moving newItem variable to state ?

Comment: You can make use of a uncontrolled input and get rid of onChange event. One you do that you can read the value of input using ref

Answer (score 0):

changed to uncontrolled input and usedReact.createRef(), suggested by [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369745/react-js-when-using-non-state-variable-getting-error-as-a-component-is-changing/53369787?noredirect=1#comment93615864_53369787)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class List extends Component {
  newItem;
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { items: [1, 2] };
    this.input = React.createRef();
  }
  changeNewItem = e => {
    this.newItem = e.target.value;
    console.log(this.newItem);
  };
  addItem = e => {
    if (e.keyCode !== 13 || !this.newItem) return;
    var new_list = this.state.items.concat(this.newItem);
    this.setState({ items: new_list }, () => {
      this.newItem = '';
      this.input.current.value = '';
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.items.map(item => (
            <li key={item}>{item}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="add item"
          ref={this.input}
          onChange={this.changeNewItem}
          onKeyUp={this.addItem}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default List;
```